# jQuery fileDownload conflicting with another jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two different jquery plugins loaded, one is UI related which allows me to display message popups and the other is the ajax fileDownload plugin. They both work fine. However, when I seem to run one function, it then starts conflicting with the other function.

I have a function called Export which initiates the fileDownload ajax request when a button is clicked. But then after the fileDownload is over, if I click on the button that launches the ExitAlert function, I end up getting the fileDownload re-initialising with the exit message. Below are the two functions.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Thanks

```
function Export() {

    $("#Form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.fileDownload('export.php?'+ Math.random(), {
                httpMethod: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                data: $('#Form').serialize(),
                successCallback: function (url) {
                    $("#ExportButton").prop("disabled", true);
                    $(pleaseWait).remove();
                },

                failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {
                    $(pleaseWait).remove();
                }
            });

    });

}









function ExitAlert() {

    $("#Form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    $.msgBox({
            title: "Are You Sure?",
            content: "<font size=2><b>Exit without saving? </b><br><br>All changes will be lost!</font>",
            opacity:0.8,
            type: "confirm",
            buttons: [{ value: "Yes" }, { value: "No" }],
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == "Yes") {
                document.Form.submit();
                    }
            }

        });

    });

}
```

Comment: Can I see the html for your button that you are clicking, or where in the code `ExitAlert` and `Export` are fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have got it to work by changing the e.preventDefault and the functions now look like this (seems to work now):

```
function Export() {

$("form").submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});

    $.fileDownload('export.php?'+ Math.random(), {
            httpMethod: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data: $('#Form').serialize(),
            successCallback: function (url) {
                $("#ExportButton").prop("disabled", true);
                $(pleaseWait).remove();
            },

            failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {
                $(pleaseWait).remove();
            }
        });

}


function ExitAlert() {


$("form").submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});

$.msgBox({
            title: "Are You Sure?",
            content: "<font size=2><b>Exit without saving? </b><br><br>All changes will be lost!</font>",
            opacity:0.8,
            type: "confirm",
            buttons: [{ value: "Yes" }, { value: "No" }],
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == "Yes") {
                document.Form.submit();
                }
        }

});

}
```